# How to store a ref globally in React & Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, semantic-ui-react

I have a lot of instances of a certain component, let's call it `<Item>`. When hovering over any `<Item>`, a (quite complex and dynamic) tooltip should appear at the item's position.

As I am using semantic-ui-react, my tool of choice is to use a `Popup` to show tooltips. One way to use popups is to give them a trigger component (which would be my `<Item>`) and a content component and it will take care of automatically being displayed in a certain position around the trigger component. But then I have one `Popup` instance for each of my items which significantly increases response time of my app since all the `Popup`s have to be created even if I don't currently need them.

Another way to use `Popup` is to give it a ref via its `context` property and it will open at that DOM node. So I would like to use this mechanism to have just a single `Popup` that will receive dynamic updates to its `context` property whenever I hover over an `<Item>`.

To do this though, I need to pass the current `<Item>` ref to the Popup. Since I have a deeply nested application, I chose to use https://github.com/diegohaz/constate for sharing state globally.

Unfortunately, sharing the ref doesn't seem to work. Whenever I try to read it from the shared context, it's null.

Please take a look at the simple example here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/pplw689627

Although I can see in a debugger that `tooltipTarget` is written to in `onMouseEnter`, when it's read in the `<Tooltip>` component, it's always null.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

I'm open to different suggestions, but I'd prefer to use Semantic's Popup if possible to keep a congruent visual style.

---

UPDATE:

Tom Finneys answer works in the sandbox above, unfortunately I'm using Typescript in my actual environment and there it doesn't work right away. I got a working solution in this sandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/7143r32klj

The main issue is that the `current` property of `RefObject<T>` is readonly. This prevents you from writing a context like this:

```
export function useTooltip() {
  const [tooltipRecipe, setTooltipRecipe] = React.useState<string | undefined>(
    undefined
  );
  let tooltipTarget = React.useRef<HTMLElement>(null);
  const setTooltipTarget = (target: HTMLElement | null) => {
    dummy.current = target;
  };
  return { tooltipRecipe, tooltipTarget, setTooltipRecipe, setTooltipTarget };
}
```

`setTooltipTarget` won't compile.

The only way I could make it work right now is to cast `RefObject<T>` to a local type where `current` is not readonly. This is quite a hack but it works. See the solution in the sandbox.

---

There's actually an ongoing discussion around this here:
https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/31065

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem stems from trying to mutate the `tooltipTarget` ref inside of the component body. You should declare another setter function in your context that you can call to change the current value of the ref.

I poked around in the sandbox a bit: https://codesandbox.io/s/p6pknz837?fontsize=14

Comment: Thank you, this is progress already. I guess I was somehow led astray by refs being mutable objects themselves. But having a setter function is much cleaner. Anyway, unfortunately it still doesn't work in my actual Typescript environment. I've updated the original post. Any ideas? Much appreciated!

Comment: Got it working now with a hack. Your solution pointed me in the right direction so I'll accept it an answer.